# Displaying one question at a time in Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have three questions in my Angular reactive form which is very basic .

I want to display only one question at a time to the user and on clicking the next button , the next question should appear . (There should be a next button underneath every question). Please help me achieve this . Thanks in advance .

[stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwjzuk)

Comment: Where are the questions in the demo? I guess your stackbilyz isn't forked properly

Comment: @AdritaSharma Please check now

Comment: @AnushaKrishnamurthy What if the user have not entered answer for first question? (Is it mandatory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the process dynamic by keeping the questions in an array.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gczdf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

TS:

```
  questions = [
    {type: "name", description : "What is your name ?", isHidden:false},
    {type: "email", description : "What is your email ?", isHidden:true},
    {type: "message", description : "What is your message ?", isHidden:true}
  ]
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of questions;let i = index">
        <div [hidden]="item.isHidden">
            {{item.description}} <input [formControlName]="item.type" placeholder="Your {{item.type}}"><br>
            <button  (click)="questions[i].isHidden = true;questions[i + 1] ?questions[i + 1].isHidden = false : false">Next</button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: @AdritaSharma Thanks a ton , I think I can proceed further with this foundation

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts declare

```
step = 1;
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="step >= 1">
    What is your name ? <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="step >= 2"> 
  What is your email? <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Your email"><br>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="step >= 3">
    What is your message? <input formControlName="message" placeholder="Your message"><br>
  </ng-container>
  <button *ngIf="step <= 2" (click)="step = step + 1;">Next</button>

</form>
```

After clicking next button step variable increments by one and it will show you the next question. [Stack Blitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3k5a2)

Answer (score 0):

**I have done this in your Reactive Form itself. Please check.**

**[Stackblitz Working Exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rztmmu)**

> Component

```
  myForm: FormGroup;
  currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('Benedict'),
      email: new FormControl(''),
      message: new FormControl(''),
      questions: new FormArray([
        new FormControl('This is Q1'),
        new FormControl('This is Q2'),
        new FormControl('This is Q3')
      ])
    });
  }
```

> HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
    What is your name ? <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    What is your email? <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Your email"><br>
    What is your message? <input formControlName="message" placeholder="Your message"><br>
    <p>
       Questions: {{ myForm.get('questions').value[currentQuestionIndex] }}
    </p>

  <button type="button" (click)="currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex - 1">Previous</button>
   &nbsp;
  <button type="button" (click)="currentQuestionIndex = currentQuestionIndex + 1">Next</button>    
</form>
```